# Updating on Mac OS X App Store

Tags: cocoa, app-store, mac-app-store

I am writing my first application. I was using Sparkle framework for updating but recently someone told me that this is not accepted by Apple on Mac App Store. So how else can I update my application? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You send updates to the app store. After being approved, they’ll be available and App Store.app will tell your users that there’s an update for your application.